is There a way to manage data interlinking hooks work in sync within a component?
As I am beginner to react, please give your thoughts...
I have two hooks:
const {data, setData} = useHook1();

const hook2data = useHook2(data.name,{...options});

I am having the above two hooks in one component.
When I set the value to data.name, then useHook2 hook makes an API Call and then returns some value. The received value will inturn  need to set to useHook1 by using the setData.
if i try to use setData, then an infinite rendering happens, and my component becomes Error.
Can I have a suggesstion to handle two hooks in same component ?
I did not used my code with useEffect

Are you asking in the very broad and general sense, which is likely not on-topic/focused enough for Stack Overflow, or do you mean in a very narrow and focused/specific use case? What do these hooks do? I'm just spit-balling here but I suspect you could handle all the logic in a single hook. Can you [edit] to provide a more complete/accurate [mcve] of the code you are trying to use?

Hi @DrewReese, my component is working with above two hooks primarily, If I try to update data.name value, it triggers an API call and returns some data. the returned data is then as per functionality, need to be applied to hook1. is this approach achievable ? Even though I have only two hooks in my work, I want to know how to utilize it effectively

"...is this approach achievable?" - Yes, provided you use the sufficient hook dependencies and conditions to prevent any render-looping.

Purely from your question and the code you provided, it's not possible to achieve what you want without infinite render.
If your second hook depends on the first hook, it's basically whenever the first hook changes, second hook will also detect the change and run. And if the second hook updates the first hook's value (probably a state), then second hook will run.
I don't know the business requirement here. From the technical point of view, most of the times in situations like this, it's better to combine those 2 hooks into one.
It'll be helpful if you can provide detailed example.

The issue you're encountering is caused by mutual dependency between the two hooks.
To resolve this issue using useEffect is the correct way to handle this scenario.
import { useEffect,useState } from 'react';

function MyComponent() {
  const { data, setData } = useState();
  const [hook2Result, setHook2Result] = useState(null);

  // Trigger `useHook2` whenever `data.name` changes
  useEffect(() => {
    if (data.name) { // Prevent unnecessary calls if data.name is null/undefined
      const fetchData = async () => {
        try {
          const result = await useHook2(data.name, { ...options });
          setHook2Result(result);
          // Update `useHook1` data if necessary
          setData((prevData) => ({
            ...prevData,
            someOtherKey: result.someValue, // Update specific fields
          }));
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Error in useHook2:", error);
        }
      };

      fetchData();
    }
  }, [data.name, setData]); // Re-run only when `data.name` changes

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Hook1 Data: {JSON.stringify(data)}</p>
      <p>Hook2 Result: {JSON.stringify(hook2Result)}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

As you are a beginner you need to know why this happen:

Your issue happens because React re-renders the component whenever state changes, so useHook2 runs again with the updated data because it have dependency for your useHook1 values, so which creating a infinite loop.

